# C# CGI executables - good or bad idea?

Tags: c#, http, xmlhttprequest, webserver

I would like to write a C# app to handle my HTTP (including AJAX requests) rather than go the PHP, PERL or ASP route as I just need to return some standard HTML, albeit obviously, as I want CGI, dynamically generated.

**UPDATE:** I am not proposing to write my own web server but have the exe hosted by a webserver such as IIS or Apache. Also I dont want to learn and use ASP (I know I can do it much faster, development time, myself in C#) and I just want W3C valid html sent back to the client.

Are there any good reasons for not doing this?

I realise each time a HTTP request is made the exe has to be loaded and run - but surely so does Perl, ASP and PHP? Is there a way to have an exe remain running dealing with all HTTP requests for specific page? (though it feels like I am just writing a mini HTTP server then!)

Are there any good tutorials? I have read this one, but it is bit dated (2005): http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/cgi_csharp.aspx

**UPDATE2:** I dont think speed is going to be a issue anyway (running a small exe without a GUI is almost instantaneous) but if I wanted to be really efficant I could write C# server then the non-static page requests can have a tiny exe written in C which sends the request to the C# server and returns the reply. Couldn't I? :)

Comment: Why would you choose to do this over running your C# in a webserver? The reason the tutorials are outdated is because the very concept is outdated.

Comment: Is this not what ASP.net is for?

Comment: @ spender I am talking about running this in a webserver - IIS to be specific but any is applicable..

Comment: @paddy I dont want learn ASP and the caveats that come along with it - I just want HTML as defined by W3C sent back to the client.

Comment: @Mrk Mnl - I think, particularly with the MVC framework, you can produce very clean HTML.  I think you're re-inventing the wheel somewhat, but it's your wheel...

Comment: What is the exact motivation for writing this yourself? ASP.Net MVC does not take more than 15 mins to get started with. As and when your functionality grows (and you introduce templates, caching, security, etc) you would be rewrtiting a subset of ASP.Net. Not a good idea!

Comment: Its just simple HTML (so its not difficult to maintain) why do I need the huge framework that is ASP. Also I like the finegrain control without all the other.. stuff, also I guees its kinda fun to do it yourself.

Answer (score 5):

There are solutions such as [FastCGI](http://www.fastcgi.com/drupal/), that eliminate the overhead of launching an executable every time you want to process a request.  Very few people still use traditional CGI.  I don't know if there is a solution compatible with .net.

There is a much better option for .NET, the `System.Web.IHttpHandler` class.

All you have to do is subclass IHttpHandler, and overload 1 method to process a request.  In my opinion it is simpler CGI.

There is a good example on the [MSDN Site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihttphandler.processrequest.aspx).

Comment: Yes there doesnt seem to be support for .Net with FastCGI - but if speed were a problem I could just have my own C# daemon then have a tiny exe's written C that handels the page requests and passes it on to the service... Or is it possible to pip IIS requests to my daemon I wonder..?

Comment: Not sure how I would make use of: System.Web.IHttpHandler, as it seems to be useful wrtting HTTP headers &c. if I were wrtting my own HTTP server - but I dont want to do that - I imgaine there will be lot more to that than one can think of immediatly esp. if I want to scale etc.

Comment: @Mrk Mnl, I think you should stop trying to solve a problem you don't have.  I don't think you will run into any scalability issues with IHttpHandler.

Comment: just to clarify are you proposing I write my own HTTP server with it?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest leveraging the [`HttpListener`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistener.aspx) API for this kind of thing if IIS really doesn't cut it for you.